# google oauth gives error in grails social plugin

Tags: java, grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

hi i am using grails social plugin for oauth authentication

the plug in can be viewed at [here](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStartedWithGrails)

just when i hit the url from index page saying
redirect to URL

```
http://localhost:8080/socialauthdemo/SAF/SocialAuth?id=google
```

it goes to google login page , but even after entering correct credentials , it sends error page , can any one help why

where the url for twitter and linked work just fine

```
http://localhost:8080/socialauthdemo/SAF/SocialAuth?id=twitter
http://localhost:8080/socialauthdemo/SAF/SocialAuth?id=linkedin
```

Comment: Have you also tried using a public domain instead of localhost as indicated here https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/HowToRunApplicationWithLocalhostOnWindows

Comment: @dmahapatro : i dont have any domain registered , how can i use any public domain ?? could you please indicate

Comment: If you follow the guidelines in the above mentioned page, you should be able to override the host entry from `localhost` to whichever domain name `example.com` (port 80) you like. Follow this link again https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/HowToRunApplicationWithLocalhostOnWindows

Comment: More details about what’s on the error page?

Comment: actually i just get a null response , thus no error message , only the response is null